# BitFinex unauthorized login

Tags: authentication, identity-theft

A few minutes ago i got an email from the real Bitfinex, saying that a unauthorized login attempt was approved by Bitfinix. Is this the work of a new breach? The IP is located somewhere in Japan.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That email seems legitimate.  You probably have cause for concern.

Contact their customer support as soon as possible.

However, do not click any links in that email. The email *might* be fake, and could be an attempt to get you to log into a fake version of their site so that they can steal your password.  The general rule is, unless you are expecting an email before you get it, verify that the email is legitimate before clicking on anything.

The next step to take is: change your password everywhere. If someone did log into your account, they probably got your username and password from a site with poor security.  Most people re-use their passwords, so malicious people will get these leaked passwords and try them out on other sites.

I strongly suggest starting to use a password manager to keep your passwords secure, and use random passwords that are different on every site.  If you can, set up 2-factor authentication on all sites, as well.  The time-based tokens (I.e., Google Authenticator) are great.  Better options are U2F devices, where you have to physically plug something into your computer's USB port or set up a Bluetooth connection.  Cell phone text message-based systems are better than nothing, but if someone is targeting you specifically, they can steal your phone number and it could be several hours before you learn that something is wrong.